# All Delete buttons are attached to the first row

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I have the following code where it display some data in rows, there's "Delete" button with each button.

in my case the "Delete" button will always delete the first row in the list, even if I try to delete something in the middle or end the last row from the list, the first row gets deleted.

not sure why all buttons are associated with the first row while they're in FOR loop.

Update#1: I did some tests and I can see that each button is aware of the correct data for it's own row, but after I click the button it hits data-target="#deleteLocation" and this new section "#deleteLocation" is always aware of the first row only.

routes.py

```
@org_settings.route("/locations", methods=["GET"])
def locations():
    form = LocationForm()
    page = request.args.get("page", 1, type=int)
    locations = (
        Location.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id)
        .order_by(Location.name.asc())
        .paginate(page=page, per_page=5)
    )
    return render_template(
        "settings/locations.html",
        title="Locations",
        locations_tab="active",
        locations=locations,
        form=form,
    )

@org_settings.route("/locations/<int:location_id>/delete", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def delete_location(location_id):
    location = Location.query.get_or_404(location_id)
    if location.organization != current_user:
        abort(403)
    db.session.delete(location)
    db.session.commit()
    flash("Your location has been deleted!", "info")
    return redirect(url_for("org_settings.locations"))
```

locations.html

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Location Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Latitude</th>
            <th scope="col">Longitude</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {% for location in locations.items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ location.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ location.latitude }}</td>
            <td>{{ location.longitude }}</td>
            <td>{{ location.address }}</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteLocation">
                    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill" style="font-size:18px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
                </button>

                <!-- Bootstrap Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="deleteLocation" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
                    aria-labelledby="deleteLocationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteLocationLabel">Delete Location</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                Are you sure you would like to delete this location?
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                <form action="{{ url_for('org_settings.delete_location', location_id=location.id) }}"
                                    method="POST">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you try to log `location_id` inside `delete_location` function to see if you're getting the expected value?

Comment: I think the problem is with the html code, because the button is aware of the correct value, but once I clock on the button it hit data-target="#deleteLocation" and under "#deleteLocation" section it's only aware of the value of the first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the ID of the row {{ location.id }} to the id of html section
data-target="#deleteLocation-{{ location.id }}"
as below

````
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#deleteLocation-{{ location.id }}">
                    <i class="bi bi-trash-fill" style="font-size:18px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></i>
                </button>```

<div class="modal fade" id="deleteLocation-{{ location.id }}" data-backdrop=" static" data-keyboard="false"
            tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="deleteLocationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
````